# Fijar el valor de un atributo de objeto seleccionado en dropdownlist a campo de texto

Tags: yii2

En yii2 quiero fijar el valor de un atributo llamado hsr de un objeto seleccionado en el dropdownlist con id #est a un campo de texto con id #hsr. Hasta ahora consigo fijar el valor del texto seleccionado en el dropdownlist pero quiero acceder al valor de otro atributo llamado hsr pero no logro hacerlo. Este es mi codigo:

```
$js = <<<JS
$("#est").on("change",function(){
  $("#hsr").val(($(this).find("option:selected").text()));
  console.log($("#hsr").val(($(this).find("option:selected").text())));
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad esta no es una pregunta como tal de Yii2, más bien es de JQuery. No sé si la única opción que tienes es con jQuery, yo te puedo dar una solución con html nativa de Yii2.

Este código va en tu controller.

```
...
$selectAnios = [ 2019 => "2019" , 2020 => "2020" , 2021 => "2021" , 2022=>"2022", 2023=>"2023" ];


        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'selectAnios' => $selectAnios,
            'anio' => $anio
        ]);
..........
```

Este código va en tu vista, en este ejemplo el año se va a seleccionar cada vez que modifiques el seect.

```
<?=Html::beginForm(['phising/'], 'get'); ?> 
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Seleccione año para gráficas</label>
 <?=Html::dropDownList('anio',$anio,$selectAnios,['class'=>'form-control','onchange'=>'this.form.submit()'] )?>
   </div>                           
  <?=Html::endForm();?>
```

Si te interesa ver las instruciones completas puedes consultar éste link: http://tutoriales-yii2.blogspot.com/2020/01/como-crear-select-sin-modelo.html